# is there any way to vimgrep, limiting to >1 but not all types of files?

Tags: vim, vimgrep

i'm pretty used to doing either:

```
:vimgrep /whatever/ **/*
```

or

```
:vimgrep /whatever/ **/*.txt
```

but is there a way with vim globbing to do, say, 2 file types? i guess i want something that would work kind of like this:

```
:vimgrep /whatever/ \*\*/.(txt|vb)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
:vimgrep /whatever/ *.{txt,vb}
```

Is what you're looking for, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
:vimgrep /whatever/ *.txt *.vb
```

Comment: great :)  as a note to anyone that wants to use this recursively as per my examples above, you can do that with :vimgrep /whatever/ \*\*/*.txt \*\*/*.vb

Answer (score 0):

I don't use vimgrep, but an (undocumented) [external](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/downloads/detail?name=searchfile.tar.bz2&can=2&q=#makechanges) perl wrapper around find+grep+xargs. From vim, your search would become:

```
:Searchfile txt,vb whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in a plugin I wrote called [EasyGrep](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2438).  It allows you to automatically search for files that match the one you're editing (with an option for recursive search) as well as files that are related to the current file.

For example: when test.cpp is open, files that match any one of *.cpp *.hpp *.cxx *.hxx *.cc *.c *.h will be searched when a search is initiated. You can also define your own relationships or create a custom one on demand.